# Compiling C++ ERROR Undefined reference to '__iob' in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I'm trying to compile an C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
fprintf(stdout, "Hello World");
return 1;
}
```

Then, executing those command line in linux to compile:

> gcc -c test.c
>
> gcc test.c -o test

and after the last command I'm getting this error message:

> undefined reference to '__iob'

Can anyone help me?

Let me know if you need any further info.

GCC version Linux Red Hat
4.8.2

GNU libc 2.17

/usr/include/stdio.h

```
/* IBM_PROLOG_BEGIN_TAG                                                   */ 
/* This is an automatically generated prolog.                             */
/*                                                                        */
/* bos720 src/bos/usr/include/stdio.h 1.46.6.4                            */
/*                                                                        */
/* Licensed Materials - Property of IBM                                   */
/*                                                                        */
/* COPYRIGHT International Business Machines Corp. 1985,1994              */
/* All Rights Reserved                                                    */
/*                                                                        */
/* US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or            */
/* disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.      */
/*                                                                        */
/* IBM_PROLOG_END_TAG                                                     */
/* @(#)77  1.46.6.4  src/bos/usr/include/stdio.h, libcio, bos720 2/2/13 04:04:36 */
```

Comment: what version of libc is installed?

Comment: it is GNU libc 2.17

Comment: `__iob` is not a glibc symbol. Any chance you were experimenting with some other libc implementation/compiler and your standard include files got overwritten by something strange? Try taking a look at the beginning of /usr/include/stdio.h, does it say where it's from?

Comment: I've added the beginning of stdio.h in the question. I also asked for the support team to reinstall the gcc with another version, and the problem still persists.

Comment: Why do you write a C-Program? What happens if you write the real  C++ Version of Hello World?

Comment: Oh I see. Your c++ tag is wrong...

Comment: That's definitely not the header file for glibc. What system (HW/OS) are you on?